# java.util.Scanner for token based processing preserving whitespace

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am attempting to create a program that processes text input and writes a "compressed" output, preserving whitespace.

The actual algorithm for compression I have been able to implement just fine, so leaving out those details in the question examples.

The main problem I am running into is how to scan in tokens of non-whitespace characters, process those tokens, and then print the final output preserving the original whitespace.

Actual input files are large text files, with many symbols and punctuation and spaceing.

However, as a simplified example, suppose I have a string:

```
"  a a b  a"
```

Notice that the line begins with two spaces, and has a double space between the last b and a characters.

For the purpose of this example, assume my processing() method was simply swapping a for b, my goal is to produce the following output:

```
"  b b a  b"
```

Right now I am reading each line with Scanner.nextLine() and then storing that line of input as a string, and processing each token with my processing() method. Note that my actual processing() method is more complicated than the example, so a simple String.replace() will not work.

```
String exampleString = "  a a b  a";

Scanner docScanner = new Scanner(exampleString);
String line = docScanner.nextLine();
Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);

while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(myProcessingMethod(lineScanner.next()));
    if (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

This works for single-spacing, but not for lines that begin with spaces or double spacing. The above attempt would produce output like:

> "b b a b"

I have tried a couple of solutions:

- checking after calling .next() to see if lineScanner.nextByte() == ' ', this does not work for leading spaces in a line.
- checking for lineScanner.hasNext(" ") and if so printing a space.
- using a different delimiter for the beginning of the line, i.e .useDelimiter("^[ ]") - however this does not work for interior double spacing.

Is there a good strategy for the kind of token-based processing as described above that would allow for processing of non-whitespace tokens while preserving whitespace before/after each token?

EDIT: 
A more concrete example in psuedocode, pretending my processing() function is simply to scramble the characters in the token.

```
String expectedOutput = "";
inputString = "  this, is. $the   input! ";

for each token in the string do:
    if the token is a space: expectedOutput.append(" ");
    else: expectedOutput.append(process(token));
done;

//expected result
expectedOutput = "  siht, si. $hte   npiut! "
```

My actual processing() function is more complex than scrambling letters, but this should give a general idea of the problem I am facing with regards to whitespace.

Comment: why don't you split string like this `String[] sn = s.split("");` and then output includes white spaces `[ ,  , a,  , a,  , a,  , b,  , a]` and also `Arrays.stream(sn).forEach(System.out::print);` will gives output `  a a a b a`

Comment: The problem with String.split("") is that for words with length > 1 it will split each char in the word into a different array element.

Comment: do you want to perform operation on characters or words? just post one realtime example of yours so that we can get much clarity

Comment: I added a bit more concrete of an example. Again, what I actually do with the words/tokens is a bit more complex, but the idea of processing a "token" and preserving whitespace is the problem at hand.